# Combine two different but pretty similar functions on onChange event

Tags: reactjs

I have two dropdowns pretty similar, both have an 'onChange' event:

```
    <Dropdown
      items={employeeNames}
      selection={employeeNames.name}
      onChange={this.handleEmployeeNamesChange}
    />
    <Dropdown
      items={employeeTypes}
      selection={employeeType.name}
      onChange={this.handleEmployeeTypeChange}
    />
```

Is there a way I can combine the two `handleChange` function to one function:

```
  handleEmployeeNameChange = newVal => {
    const newState = { ...this.state, employeeNames: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState, isValid: getValidation(newState) });
  };

  handleEmployeeTypeChange= newVal => {
    const newState = { ...this.state, employeeTypes: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState, isValid: getValidation(newState) });
  };
```

Comment: declare one function and when you are calling it on onClick pass a argument let say "name" and type for another one and check it where you have declared and set the state as you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a *factory* method that creates functions for each change handler you want

```js
handleGenericChange = changedProperty => newVal => {
    const newState = { ...this.state, [changedProperty]: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState, isValid: getValidation(newState) });
}

handleEmployeeNameChange = handleGenericChange('employeeNames')
handleEmployeeTypeChange = handleGenericChange('employeeTypes')
```

Comment: Ahah same answer at the same time, I keep mine who's write with a different syntax

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to create a method to combine your changes and pass parameters.

The final goal is to update the right `key` of your `state`, use this key as parameter.

```
<Dropdown
  items={employeeNames}
  selection={employeeNames.name}
  onChange={v => this.handleChangeDropdown("employeeNames",v)}
/>
<Dropdown
  items={employeeTypes}
  selection={employeeType.name}
  onChange={v => this.handleChangeDropdown("employeeTypes",v)}
/>

handleChangeDropdown = (key,newVal) => {
  this.setState({
     [key]:newVal,
     isValid: getValidation(newState)
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a code review question. Yes, there is :

```
handleEmployeeChange = category => newVal => {
   const newState = { ...this.state, [category]: newVal };
   this.setState({ ...newState, isValid: getValidation(newState) });
};
```

Setting a second argument to your arrow function allow it to be preconfigured for later use :

```
<Dropdown
  items={employeeNames}
  selection={employeeNames.name}
  onChange={this.handleEmployeeChange('employeeNames')}
/>
<Dropdown
  items={employeeTypes}
  selection={employeeType.name}
  onChange={this.handleEmployeeChange('employeeTypes')}
/>
```

You can even map your Dropdown components to avoid any repetition :

```
['employeeNames', 'employeeTypes'].map(param => {
    <Dropdown
        items={data[param]}
        selection={data[param].name}
        onChange={this.handleEmployeeChange(param)}
        key={data[param].name} //If their name is unique
    />
})
```

Your values will just have to be in an object :

```
data = {
    employeeNames: '',
    employeeTypes: ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function on change and add name of state you want to change

```
<Dropdown
  items={employeeNames}
  selection={employeeNames.name}
  onChange={(v) => this.handleEmployeeChange('employeeNames', v)}
/>
<Dropdown
  items={employeeTypes}
  selection={employeeType.name}
  onChange={(v) => this.handleEmployeeChange('employeeTypes', v)}
/>
```

And

```
  handleEmployeeChange = (field, newVal) => {
    const newState = { ...this.state, field: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState, isValid: getValidation(newState) });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
    <Dropdown
      items={employeeNames}
      selection={employeeNames.name}
      onChange={this.handleEmployeeChange.bind(this, "name")}
    />

   <Dropdown
      items={employeeTypes}
      selection={employeeType.name}
      onChange={this.handleEmployeeChange.bind(this, "type")}
   />
```

in declaration

```
handleEmployeeChange(val){
    val === "name" ? const newState = { ...this.state, employeeNames: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState, isValid: getValidation(newState) });
    : 
    const newState = { ...this.state, employeeTypes: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState, isValid: getValidation(newState) });
}
```